# Polymer 2.0: iron-icon not working in Starter kit

Tags: polymer-starter-kit

I am newbie in Polymer projects, I have installed polymer 2.0 starterkit, everything works fine except iron-icon. It doesn't display icon when i run project.

```
    <!-- Load the Polymer.Element base class -->
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">

    <script src="../bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icon/iron-icon.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-iconset-svg/iron-iconset-svg.html">

    <dom-module id="my-iconsset-view">
      <!-- Defines the element's style and local DOM -->
      <template>
        <style>
          :host {
            display: block;

            padding: 16px;
          }
        </style>

        <h1>My Iconsc</h1>

        <iron-icon icon="icon:menu"></iron-icon>
        <iron-icon icon="input"></iron-icon>


      </template>
      <script>
        // Your new element extends the Polymer.Element base class
        class MyIconssetView extends Polymer.Element {
          static get is() { return 'my-iconsset-view'; }
        }
        //Now, register your new custom element so the browser can use it
        customElements.define(MyIconssetView.is, MyIconssetView);
      </script>
    </dom-module>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import `<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">` instead of just `iron-icon`.

Also, you don't have to mention `icon="icon:menu"`, just `icon="menu"` is fine, unless you have defined your own `iconset` and named as 'icon'.

> The `iron-icon` element is used for displaying an icon.
>
> `iron-icons` is a utility import that includes the definition for the
>   `iron-icon` element, `iron-iconset-svg` element, as well as an import
>   for the default icon set.

Comment: I changed the folder and html file from iron-icon to iron-icons and imported

<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html"> and made changes to 

 <iron-icon icon="menu"></iron-icon>

but still it does't work, please help

Comment: @iRav Did you install iron-irons?